# Styling Highmap Legend

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I was trying to stylize the legend of highmap

[image]

I succesfully changed the background color and the title color of the legend, but not able to change the color of the white ticks seprating recatangles in legend and the caption of each each rectabgle (1, 10, 100, 1k...)

What i have tried..

```
legend: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Population density per km²',
                    style: {
                        color: '#ff0000'
                    }
                },
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
                borderWidth: 0,
                borderRadius: 0,
                itemStyle: {
                    color: '#ff0000'
                }
            }
```

How can i change the color of 1, 10, 100, 1k and the colors of the rectangles..

Answer (score 0):

You can configure that by `dateClasses` in [colorAxis](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#colorAxis.dataClasses).

```
colorAxis: {

                    dataClasses: [{
                        from: -100,
                        to: 0,
                        color: '#C40401',
                        name: 'Romney'
                    }, {
                        from: 0,
                        to: 100,
                        color: '#0200D0',
                        name: 'Obama'
                    }]
                },
```

Comment: So i want these data classes to genrate dynamically as they are genrating, i just want to change the tick color and tick height?